Have an automatically highlighted button in an a active class script
I've got a list of buttons that change the font family of my text. I wanted to change the border and text color when a certain option was chosen.
I've got this javascript that works well, but when the screen is first loaded, the font family chosen isn't highlighted, and I have to click the button for it to show up the first time. How do I make the font that is automatically loaded (Georgia) be highlighted already before it is changed?


var fontbtns = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");
for (var i = 0; i < fontbtns.length; i++) {
  fontbtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("fontactive");
    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" fontactive", "");
    }
    this.className += " fontactive";
  });
}
.grid-item.fontactive {
  border-color: #06a0ff;
  color: #06a0ff;
}
<div class="fontsgrid" id="fontlist">
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-garamond" onclick="changeFontFamily('EB Garamond')">Garamond</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-palatino" onclick="changeFontFamily('Palatino')">Palatino</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-bookerly" onclick="changeFontFamily('Bookerly')">Bookerly</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-georgia" onclick="changeFontFamily('Georgia')">Georgia</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-baskerville" onclick="changeFontFamily('Baskerville')">Baskerville</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-montserrat" onclick="changeFontFamily('Montserrat')">Montserrat</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-futura" onclick="changeFontFamily('Futura')">Futura</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-opendyslexic3" onclick="changeFontFamily('OpenDyslexic3')">Open Dyslexic</button>
</div>




Just add the fontactive class to the desired button.


var fontbtns = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");
for (var i = 0; i < fontbtns.length; i++) {
  fontbtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("fontactive");
    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" fontactive", "");
    }
    this.className += " fontactive";
  });
}
.grid-item.fontactive {
  border-color: #06a0ff;
  color: #06a0ff;
}
<div class="fontsgrid" id="fontlist">
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-garamond" onclick="changeFontFamily('EB Garamond')">Garamond</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-palatino" onclick="changeFontFamily('Palatino')">Palatino</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-bookerly" onclick="changeFontFamily('Bookerly')">Bookerly</button>
  <button class="grid-item fontactive" id="ff-georgia" onclick="changeFontFamily('Georgia')">Georgia</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-baskerville" onclick="changeFontFamily('Baskerville')">Baskerville</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-montserrat" onclick="changeFontFamily('Montserrat')">Montserrat</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-futura" onclick="changeFontFamily('Futura')">Futura</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-opendyslexic3" onclick="changeFontFamily('OpenDyslexic3')">Open Dyslexic</button>
</div>



But also don't use getElementsByClassName() as this returns a "live" node list that can impact performance, especially when the list is iterated over as you are doing. Instead use .querySelectorAll(), which returns a static node list.
So, with that change, the code would be:


// .querySelectorAll() returns a node list that implements the 
// Array.prototype.forEach() method, which makes looping much
// simpler.
document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item").forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".fontactive").forEach(function(element){
      element.classList.remove("fontactive");
    });
    item.classList.add("fontactive");
  });
});


function changeFontFamily(){}
.grid-item.fontactive {
  border-color: #06a0ff;
  color: #06a0ff;
}
<div class="fontsgrid" id="fontlist">
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-garamond" onclick="changeFontFamily('EB Garamond')">Garamond</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-palatino" onclick="changeFontFamily('Palatino')">Palatino</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-bookerly" onclick="changeFontFamily('Bookerly')">Bookerly</button>
  <button class="grid-item fontactive" id="ff-georgia" onclick="changeFontFamily('Georgia')">Georgia</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-baskerville" onclick="changeFontFamily('Baskerville')">Baskerville</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-montserrat" onclick="changeFontFamily('Montserrat')">Montserrat</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-futura" onclick="changeFontFamily('Futura')">Futura</button>
  <button class="grid-item" id="ff-opendyslexic3" onclick="changeFontFamily('OpenDyslexic3')">Open Dyslexic</button>
</div>



Now, a different approach would be to utilize radio buttons because only one from a group can be selected at any given time and that would eliminate the need for loops in your code. But, instead of showing the radio buttons, we'll use CSS to hide them and only show their related label elements, which will be styled to look like buttons.
This approach uses a bit more HTML, but much less JavaScript.
See the comments inline below.


// Set the default font
document.body.style.fontFamily = "Consolas";

// Whatever "button" gets clicked, the event will bubble up to the parent
// "wrapper" element and be handled there
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Set the font of the page to the value of the checked radio button within the wrapper that got clicked.   
  // event.target is a reference to the element that triggered the event in the first place.
  document.body.style.fontFamily = event.target.value;
});
/* Hide the radio buttons */
input[type='radio'] { display:none; }

/* Default styling for labels to make them look like buttons */
input[type='radio'] + label {
  display:inline-block;
  box-shadow:1px 1px grey;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 80px;
  font-size:.6em;
  text-align:center;
}

/* Styling for labels when corresponding radio button is checked */
input[type='radio']:checked + label {
  box-shadow:-1px -1px grey;
  background-color:#f78d32;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="rad" value="Comic Sans MS">
  <label for="rad1">Comic Sans</label>

  <!-- Use the checked attribute to pre-select a choice -->
  <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad" value="Consolas" checked>
  <label for="rad2">Consolas</label>

  <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="rad" value="Calibri">
  <label for="rad3">Calibri</label>

  <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="rad" value="Georgia">
  <label for="rad4">Georgia</label>

  <input type="radio" id="rad5" name="rad" value="Arial">
  <label for="rad5">Arial</label>

  <input type="radio" id="rad6" name="rad" value="Montserrat">
  <label for="rad6">Montserrat</label>

  <input type="radio" id="rad7" name="rad" value="Baskerville Old Face">
  <label for="rad7">Baskerville</label>

  <input type="radio" id="rad8" name="rad" value="Harrington">
  <label for="rad8">Harrington</label>
</div>

<h1>Page Heading</h1>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>




Stop using className.replace() and use classList.remove().

@Barmar I using classList.remove() in my suggested alternative codes.

You can simplify this if you use data attributes and move the event handler attachment to the script.  Here I use the values of the data element - not all fonts are downloaded but for one that is sans-serif you can see where I added that fallback hence it uses it.
I removed all the ids as not needed also - simpler HTML that way.


function handleFontChangeClick(event) {
  const currentActive = document.querySelectorAll('.fontactive');
  currentActive.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.toggle("fontactive", false);
  });
  this.classList.toggle("fontactive", true);
}
// add a click handler to the nodes - buttons in this case
const fontbtns = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
fontbtns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', handleFontChangeClick));

//direct way to set class
// fontbtns[fontbtns.length - 1].classList.toggle("fontactive", true);

//better way enact functional "click" change?
//fontbtns[fontbtns.length - 1].click();

// set a specific font from the list?
const defaultFontFamily = "Georgia";
const fh = [...fontbtns].filter((el) => {
  return el.dataset.fontfam == defaultFontFamily;
}).pop().click(); //set on first one via click

//set the fonts for the buttons to the values
for (const btn of fontbtns) {
  btn.style.fontFamily = btn.dataset.fontfam;
}
.grid-item.fontactive {
  border-color: #06a0ff;
  color: #06a0ff;
}
<div class="fontsgrid" id="fontlist">
  <button class="grid-item" data-fontfam="EB Garamond">Garamond</button>
  <button class="grid-item" data-fontfam="Palatino">Palatino</button>
  <button class="grid-item" data-fontfam="Bookerly">Bookerly</button>
  <button class="grid-item" data-fontfam="Georgia">Georgia</button>
  <button class="grid-item" data-fontfam="Baskerville">Baskerville</button>
  <button class="grid-item" data-fontfam="Montserrat,sans-serif">Montserrat</button>
  <button class="grid-item" data-fontfam="Futura">Futura</button>
  <button class="grid-item" data-fontfam="OpenDyslexic3">Open Dyslexic</button>
</div>



